# Infinite product $\prod_{ m = 1 }^{ \infty } { \cos (\frac{ x }{ 4 ^ { m }}) }$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations, infinite-product

I'm trying to figure out this infinite product: $
   f  (  x )   =  \prod_{ m = 1 }^{  \infty  } {  \cos (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { m }}) } $

I did the same trick as in the $2^m$ version to get this functional equation: $
 f(x)  \times  f(2x)  = \frac{ \sin ( x )}{ x }
$

And now im really stuck, I'm not even sure if there's only one solution for this equation. I thought convolution might work but that was messy..

My main question is how to solve this infinite product, but anything about this equation will be great too.

Thanks!

What i did was:
$
 f(x)=  \prod_{ m = 1 }^{  \infty  } {  \cos (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { m }}) }  =  \lim_{N \to  \infty }   \prod_{ m = 1 }^{ N } {  \cos (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { m }}) }    =  \lim_{N \to  \infty }   \prod_{ m = 1 }^{ N } { \frac{ \sin (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ {   m  -  1   }})}{   4  \times  \sin (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { m }})   \times  \cos (\frac{ 2x }{ 4  ^ { m }})} }    =  \lim_{N \to  \infty }  \frac{ \sin ( x )}{   4  ^ { N } \times  \sin (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { N }})   \times  \prod_{ m = 1 }^{ N } {  \cos (\frac{ 2x }{ 4  ^ { m }}) } }   = \frac{ \sin ( x )}{ x }   \lim_{N \to  \infty }  \frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { N } \times  \sin (\frac{ x }{ 4  ^ { N }})}     \lim_{N \to  \infty }  \frac{ 1 }{ \prod_{ m = 1 }^{ N } {  \cos (\frac{ 2x }{ 4  ^ { m }}) } }   = \frac{ \sin ( x )}{ x } \times  1  \times \frac{ 1 }{ f    \left(  2x  \right) } $

Comment: @metamorphy. *Terrific* or *Terrible* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comments.*  Probabilistic viewpoint:
Let $X_n, n=1,2,3,\dots$ be IID random variables with
$\mathbb P(X_n = 1)=\mathbb P(X_n = -1)=\frac12$.  Fix $r \in (0,1)$.Consider the rancom variable
$$
Z_r = \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n X_n .
$$
Then your function is $f_{1/4}$, where
$$
f_r  (  x )   =  \prod_{ m = 1 }^{  \infty  }   \cos \left(r^n x\right) 
$$
is the **characteristic function** of $Z_{r}$, that is:
$$
\mathbb E\left[\exp\big(ixZ_{r}\big)\right] = f_r(x) .
$$
In the case $r=1/2$, note that $Z_{1/2}$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, so
$$
f_{1/2}(x) = \frac12\int_{-1}^1 e^{ixz}\,dz = \frac{\sin x}{x} .
$$
But for the case in this question, $r=1/4$, the random variable $Z_{1/4}$ has a singular distribution, concentrated on a Cantor set.  (A fractal measure.)  And $f_{1/4}$ is the characteristic function of that fractal measure.

---

But of course "known" functions do not have continuous singular Fourier transforms; so it is unlikely that $f_{1/4}$ can be written in terms of standard special functions.

Comment: There is a classic question of Erdõs asking about whether the distribution of $Z_r$ is singular or absolutely continuous. $0<r<\frac12$ singular of course. $r=\frac12$ absolutely continuous. But what about $\frac12 < r < 1$? There are known values of $r$ in each camp.  Considerable progress has been made, which I will not review here.

Answer (score 1):

*Not more exciting than @metamorphy*

Using my favored $1,400$ years old approximation
$$\cos(t) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4t^2}{\pi ^2+t^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad t\in  \left(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right)$$

Using the q-Pochhammer symbol

$$P_n=\prod_{ m = 1 }^{ n} { \cos \left(\frac{x}{4^m}\right)}\sim(-1)^{n+1}\, 4^{n+1}\,\frac{\pi ^2+x^2}{\pi ^2-4x^2}\,\frac{\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{4 x^2};16\right){}_{n+1}}{\left(-\frac{\pi
   ^2}{x^2};16\right){}_{n+1}}$$

Let $ x=\frac \pi k$ to make
$$P_n\sim (-1)^{n+1}\, 4^{n+1}\,\frac{k^2+1}{k^2-4}\,\frac{\left(\frac{k^2}{4};16\right){}_{n+1}}{\left(-k^2;16\right){}_{n+1}}$$

Computing $P_{1000}$ for various $k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 3 & 0.963283 & 0.963720 \\
 4 & 0.979268 & 0.979525 \\
 5 & 0.986708 & 0.986876 \\
 6 & 0.990761 & 0.990879 \\
 7 & 0.993208 & 0.993295 \\
 8 & 0.994798 & 0.994865 \\
 9 & 0.995889 & 0.995942 \\
 10 & 0.996669 & 0.996712 \\
 11 & 0.997247 & 0.997283 \\
 12 & 0.997686 & 0.997716
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using
$$\log (\cos (t))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{4^{n-1} } {(2n)! } (E_{2 n-1}(1)-E_{2 n-1}(0))\,\, t^{2n}$$ with $t=\frac x {4^m}$

$$P_n=1-\frac{x^2}{30}+\frac{7 x^4}{30600}-\frac{59 x^6}{83538000}+\frac{54121
   x^8}{43797302640000}-\frac{21679 x^{10}}{15676653564000000}+\frac{7892306381
   x^{12}}{7364296445064839280000000}-\frac{3966051541499
   x^{14}}{6515855851628919146551200000000}++O\left(x
   ^{16}\right)$$